Excel VBA Function with Match and Index
I am trying to write a function to use Match and Index to perform a lookup down a column and across two rows for a more complex lookup.  I have a spreadsheet where row 3 uses the formula which works but my VBA function is now working as called from row 4.  The formula bar is showing C4 passing the parameters.  My actual application is more complicated with case conditions with more parameters and the lookup tables will be on various worksheets.  I am trying the simple method first.  I am wondering if it's a limitation of the Index being used in the VBA.
I added the AddTwoNumbers function just to text and make sure everything was working OK. :)

Function LookupRate(Code As String, Shift As String, Class As String)

LookupRate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Wages").Range("$B$10:$J$12"), WorksheetFunction.Match(Code, Sheets("Wages").Range("$A$10:$A$12"), 0), WorksheetFunction.Match(Shift & Class, Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Wages").Range("$B$9:$J$9") & Sheets("Wages").Range("$B$8:$J$8"), 0), 0))

End Function

Function AddTwoNumbers(Num1 As Long, Num2 As Long)

AddTwoNumbers = Num1 + Num2

End Function


Just as a side note, at least half of your problems step from the fact that your input data is not normalised.  Change it to something like - https://i.sstatic.net/O93HG7H1.png and your life will become much easier.

I have to agree that my thought too was to make this easier by structuring the data better, so you can use "normal" functions and not resort to special code just to read data from a table (although I'm sure an excel wizard with time and gumptions could find a solution with whatever you provide, having well structured data is just always desirable).

While the comments of the other posters go without saying, your particular layout (in that all of your classes are the same size, and they all have the same "divisions" in the same order), you can use an ampersand-less syntax =INDEX($B$10:$J$12,MATCH(C$1,$A$10:$A$12,0),MATCH($B4,$B$8:$J$8,0)+MATCH(C$2,$B$9:$J$9,0)-1) which can be codified directly in VBA (btw. by using With Application.WorksheetFunction .... End With you will render your code more readable.

Thanks everyone..... The tables are very large and they are given by another source as they can get updated.  I was trying to not have to change them from their original format every time.  I know I could write something to do that too I guess....

Thanks @SpectralInstance that worked perfectly!  I used your follow up below.

Further to my comment, the VBA version
Function LookupRate(Code As String, Shift As String, Class As String)
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        LookupRate = .Index(Sheets("Wages").Range("B10:J12"), .Match(Code, Sheets("Wages").Range("A10:A12"), 0), _
            .Match(Class, Sheets("Wages").Range("B8:J8"), 0) + .Match(Shift, Sheets("Wages").Range("B9:J9"), 0) - 1)
    End With
End Function

Since you want a unique number returned, you could also use a SUMPRODUCT()- based approach, although I always have to resort to the Evaluate() method in  VBA for this, i.e.
Function LookupRate(Code As String, Shift As String, Class As String)
    SumRate = Worksheets("Wages").Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(Wages!B10:J12*(Wages!B8:J8=""" & Class & """)*(Wages!B9:J9=""" & Shift & """)*(Wages!A10:A12=""" & Code & """))")
End Function

